# radially unbounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, infinity, control-theory, lyapunov-functions

Is the following function radially unbounded or not?
$$V(x) = \frac{x_{1}^2}{1 + x_{1}^2} + x_{2}^2$$
I know that if $x_{2} \to \infty$ in which case $||x|| \to \infty$ and $V(x) \to \infty$ but if $x_{1} \to \infty$ which makes $||x|| \to \infty$ but then $V(x)$ does not go to  $\infty$. What I would like to know is that is a function radially unbounded if only one or more of its variables makes it go to infinity or should it be true for every variable that that function depends on?

Edit: I am not a student of math. In a engineering subject, this popped up. I have seen other answers but can't get my head around it. So can you kindly answer the question in simpler words? instead of down voting the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it geometrically. The condition that $V(x)$ is radially unbounded means that all level sets are closed. Now, take $x_2 = 0$ and determine the level set $V(x) = 1$, you get

$$
V(x_1, 0) = \frac{x_1^2}{1 + x_1^2} = 1. \tag{1}
$$

Obviously, this cannot hold for finite $x_1$, so $V(x)$ is radially bounded.

**Edit**: To adress your second question, I will give an example. In general it means that any combination of $x_1$, $x_2$ that makes $||x|| \rightarrow \infty$ also has to make $V(x)\rightarrow \infty$.

This holds for any norm, but lets assume Euclidean norm for simplicity. Since for $x_1 \rightarrow \infty, x_2 = 0$ you get $||x||_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} = \sqrt{\infty^2 + 0^2} \rightarrow \infty$. However, for $V(x)$, you get in this case

$$
\lim_{x_1 \rightarrow \infty} V(x_1, 0) = 1 \neq \infty.
$$

So your function is not radially unbounded.

Comment: I just got more confused (I suck at math). Is that a yes for my question?

Comment: @JibranEjaz It's a no: the function is not radially unbounded.

Comment: Dang it. I thought I edited the last comment. What I wanted to say was that is it bounded because $V(x)$ doesn't go to $\infty$ as $x_{1} \to \infty$?

Comment: By the way i did some research and I understand your answer now. But can I say 
that, what I said in my second comment?

Comment: @JibranEjaz I edited my answer.